# How to access response headers in React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, fetch, response, response-headers

I am having troubles with some requests I am making from my React Native app, to my NodeJS server.

One of the endpoints being called, can return a `409` error for one of two reasons, therefore I need to access the message that was thrown along with this error.

I can see the message in the Response Headers in Chrome's Dev Tools, but I am struggling to access it.

```
  await fetch(
    new Request(`${Constants?.manifest?.extra?.hostname}/ext/external-users`, {
      method: 'POST',
    }),
    {
      body: formData,
      headers,
    }
  ).then(async response => {
    if (response.status == 200) {
      await response.json().then(({ externalUser, token }) => {
        result.createdUser = externalUser
        result.tabledAuthToken = token
      })
    } else if (response.status == 409) {
      const errorMessage = response.headers.get('x-exit')
      if (errorMessage?.toLowerCase() === ERROR_MESSAGES.INVALID_VERSION) {
        throw new Error(ERROR_MESSAGES.INVALID_VERSION)
      }
      throw Error(`There was a problem when trying to log in user: ${emailAddress}. Please, try again later.`)
    }
  })
```

When I log the output of `errorMessage`, it is just `null`. I have seen people say to use `.json().then(...)`, but this fails because `response` is not a `JSON`.

Comment: what if you log out `response.headers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue, the problem was in our backend server. Me and a co-worker worked in parallel on a feature. In the backend, he forgot to add `allowResponseHeaders: 'x-exit'` to our security file. Once this was added, I was able to get the error message from the response headers.

Comment: I think the answer is related to the issue you were trying to resolve by accessing the response headers. In this answer you are not clarifying, how to access the response header in react native. Please use comments in future for this kind of messages. You can also edit the question to provide more details on what you are trying to achieve.